# PHP get generated source of a file gotten using file_get_contents or curl

Tags: php

I am writing an audit for our website to see what detail pages are displayed based on a selection.  The website is written and maintained by a 3rd party.  The issue is when I pull the file such as:

$page = file_get_contants('https://example.com/search=red');

It returns source which is the pre generated source which is a template and then uses ajax calls to get the relevant data and then builds the final page from that and the generated code is what I would like to parse to get the links to the detail pages.

I am thinking something like wkhtmltopdf only which would do it to generated source.  Does anyone know of a php library which can do this or a linux package that can do this which a I could call from php?

Comment: Hi! Recommendation questions are not allowed here according to the [help], but as a hint you might want to search for "web scraping". The key is that you need an actual (or simulated) browser to make all those extra requests, there's no shortcut to get a "final" version of a page.

Comment: wkhtmltopdf won't run JavaScript to build the final page either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle dynamic content loading, you might want to consider using a headless browser or a tool designed for web scraping with JavaScript rendering capabilities. Puppeteer is one such tool, and it's commonly used with Node.js for tasks like this. However, you can use a PHP library that wraps around a headless browser as well.

One such PHP library is Goutte, which uses Symfony components and provides a simple interface for web scraping. It's built on top of Guzzle and Symfony BrowserKit. Here's a basic example of how you might use Goutte for your task:

```php
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://yoursite.com/search=red');

$links = $crawler->filter('a')->links();

foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo $link->getUri() . "\n";
}
```

Remember to install Goutte and its dependencies using Composer:

```bash
composer require fabpot/goutte
```

Comment: so would I just need to install Goutte using composer on my server or would I need to install additional browser for the head?

Comment: no! you can use terminal

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand quite well what are you trying to accomplish, i guess you are trying to do some web scraping to get the content of various pages?

Nonetheless, here are some packages that will help you with this:

- [Guzzle PHP](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/)
- [Panther](https://github.com/symfony/panther)